# A page contains 2 elements with the same "id", how can I find the one I need?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm running a python script which fills out a form on a html page using selenium. The page contains 2 divs and one of them is hidden, they switch their state visible/hidden depending on a radio button. And those 2 divs have similar elements-inputs which have exactly the same `id`s. Hence, when I want to find an element in 2nd visible div, I actually find it in 1st invisible one.

```
# 2 elements with the same id on the page 
# one of them is hidden because it's in a hidden div

e1 = driver.find_element_by_id("some_id")
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to *find all/both divs and filter the [visible one](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_displayed)*:

```
visible_div = next(div for div in driver.find_elements_by_id("some_id") 
                   if div.is_displayed())
```

Or, you may just get the desired `div` by index (if this is applicable):

```
desired_div = driver.find_elements_by_id("some_id")[1]  # the second one
```

Comment: can `find_elements_by_id` return 2 elements?

Comment: @AlanCoromano yup, it would return all elements with a given id.